# How do I use L'Hopital's rule to determine if $\log^kN$ is $o(N)$ for any constant $k$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, computer-science

How do I apply L'Hopital's rule to see if $\log^kN$ is $o(N)$ (small $o$) for any constant $k$?

I understand I should keep finding the derivatives of both functions and stop if I can clearly identify a value but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: What is $\log^k(x)$? It could be the k-fold composition $\log(\log(…(\log(x))…))$ or the power $\log(x)^k$.

Comment: I do know that the derivative of log^k(x) is k log^(k-1)(x) but I'm not sure how to apply this for comparing the growth rate

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $\log^k(N)$ is $o(N)$. By definition of small-oh, you want to show that
$$\frac{\log^k(N)}{N}\to 0,$$
for $N\to\infty$. If the limit exists, we have by L'Hôpital that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\log^k(N)}{N} = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dN}\log^k(N)}{\frac{d}{dN}N} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{k\log^{k-1}(N)\frac{1}{N}}{1} = k\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-1}(N)}{N}.$$
Applying L'Hôpital $k-1$ more times, we get
$$k\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-1}(N)}{N} = k\cdot (k-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} = 0,$$
which is what we set out to show.

Edit: Elaborating on the last line. If you apply L'Hôpital one time to the limit $k\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-1}(N)}{N}$, then you get
$$k\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-1}(N)}{N} = k\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{(k-1)\log^{k-2}(N)\frac{1}{N}}{1}=k(k-1)\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-2}(N)}{N}.$$

You see that the exponent of $\log$ falls by $1$ each time we apply L'Hôpital, and notice also the factor that we get out front. If I apply L'Hôpital again to $k(k-1)\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-2}(N)}{N}$, I get $k(k-1)(k-2)\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-3}(N)}{N}$, and so forth. At some point, the exponent of $\log$ will be $0$, which is why I end up with $k(k-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: Thank you! The only part I don't understand is the last line;
$$k\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\log^{k-1}(N)}{N} = k\cdot (k-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} = 0,$$

How did you get
$$\cdots 2$$
And what does it mean?

Comment: @StevenChen Ok, I have elaborated on the last line. By $k\cdot (k-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1$, I mean the product of all the numbers between $k$ and $1$, so $k\cdot (k-1)\cdot (k-2)\cdot (k-3)\cdots $ and so on, until we reach $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use that
$$
\frac{\log^k N}{N}=\frac{(2k)^k}{\sqrt N}·\left(\frac{\log\sqrt[2k]N}{\sqrt[2k]N}\right)^k
$$
and then use that $\log x/x$ is bounded.